# How to calculate minutes between to date/time in PHP using DateTime::createFromFormat?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Using the `DateTime::createFromFormat` how can I calculate the different in minutes between `$dt1` and `$dt2` with `$dt2` being the later time?

I have tried `$dt2 - $dt1`, but that produces an `error`, of course.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// $time1 will always be in HH:MM:SS MM/DD/YYYY format.
$time1 = "08:18:00 07/11/2013";

// $time2 will always be in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format.
$time2 = "7/11/2013 9:11:00 AM";

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $time1);
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $time2);
var_dump($dt1);
var_dump($dt2);
if ($dt1 < $dt2) echo "The first is earlier" . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Perhaps using the [diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could have been answered by simply reading the [DateTime](http://PHP.net/DateTime) manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$time1 = "08:18:00 07/11/2013";
$time2 = "7/11/2013 9:11:00 AM";
$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $time1);
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $time2);
$interval = $dt1->diff($dt2);
echo $interval->format("%i")." minutes";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)**.

> `DateTime::diff` -- `DateTimeImmutable::diff` -- `DateTimeInterface::diff` -- `date_diff` — Returns the difference between two DateTime objects